# UIView drawRect called repeatedly

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, drawrect

I have a custom UIView where I see drawRect being called many times in a second even though I do not call setNeedsDisplay in code. I do not want to repeatedly draw the same content unless there is an update. How do I stop drawRect to be invoked unnecessarily? Documentation of drawRect says it is not invoked unless setNeedsDisplay/setNeedsDisplayInRect is called. But I do not see that happening in the debugger. The debugger simply shows the sequence -- UIApplicationMain , myView.draw

EDIT: I found the problem. I am doing a setNeedsDisplay in viewWillLayoutSubviews. The question now is why is viewWillLayoutSubviews called repeatedly.

Comment: at the time application launch called?

Comment: No, nearly every second.